# table2excel exclude not working

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

```
$("td:hidden").addClass("noExl");

$("#estTbl").table2excel({
   exclude: ".noExl",
   name: "file1",
   filename: projectCode+'-'+ startDate+' to'+ endDate ,
   fileext: ".xls",
   exclude_img: true,
   exclude_links: true,
   exclude_inputs: true
});
```

This doesn't exclude hidden TDs. How can i add "noExl" manually to hidden TDs.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide a single `td` but in that case the next td will move in the place previous hidden td see below snippet,

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('#export-btn').on('click', function(e){
        $("#estTbl").table2excel({
            exclude: ".noExl",
            name: "Data",
            filename: "tblExport.xlsx",
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/rainabba/jquery-table2excel/1.1.0/dist/jquery.table2excel.min.js"></script>
<button id="export-btn">Export</button>
<table id="estTbl">
  <thead>
    <tr class="noExl">
      <td>This shouldn't get exported</td>
      <td>This shouldn't get exported either</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This Should get exported as a header</td>
      <td>This should too</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="noExl">This too data1a</td>
      <td>data1b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data2a</td>
      <td>data2b</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">This footer spans 2 cells</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Is there a way to remove hidden TDs before export and restore them after export?

Comment: I add table dynamically. and  need to add noExl class too.

Comment: If you are adding table dynamically then add `noExl` class at server end for the columns which should not export.

Comment: arrtSetting = function (rowId, val, rawObject, cm) {
            var attr = rawObject.attr[cm.name], result;
            if (attr.rowspan) {
                result = ' rowspan=' + '"' + attr.rowspan + '"';
            } else if (attr.display) {
                result = ' style="display:' + attr.display + '", class= "noExl"';
            } else {
                result = null;
            }
            return result;
        };


this is cellattr function for one column

Comment: And your `rawObject`,`cm` values?

Comment: JSON of the row object

Comment: Due to insufficient data(like row object) and code I can't help you. If possible then share your full code and/or create a snippet/fiddle to solve this problem.