# Table2excel exclude inline a div

Tags: html, jquery, export

I have an HTML table. There are buttons in the rows of this table that allow me to perform operations. Whhen exporting the table with jQuery table2excel, these buttons are also taken into account and an unwanted result comes out.
Is there any way I can exclude these buttons?
Including it in the .noExl class did not work. It ignores the whole line.

```
$("#excelBtn").click(function () {
    $("#table").table2excel({
        exclude: ".noExl",
        name: "Worksheet Name",
        filename: "SomeFile",
        fileext: ".xls",
        exclude_img: true,
        exclude_links: true,
        exclude_inputs: true
    });
});
```

Comment: please provide the code of the table and specifically share, which lines you want excluded and what the (unwanted) outcome is. without seeing your usage of <tr class="noExl"> we cannot help you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: did you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43736124/table2excel-exclude-not-working

Comment: and this: https://github.com/rainabba/jquery-table2excel/issues/9

Comment: this plugin allows to exlude cells: https://github.com/kayalshri/tableExport.jquery.plugin